# Android: show remaining time in human readable format

Tags: android, datetime, datetime-format

I got a timestamp (UTC) which is in the future. Now I want to show the remaining time from now on in a human readable format like "**2h 15min**". But I'm not sure which method of the DateUtils is the best way. Any suggestions? I was thinking of:

> [DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString(long,%20long,%20long,%20int))

That's a sample code:

```
            int gmtOffset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
            long utcTimestamp = item.getExpirationDate();
            long localTimestamp = utcTimestamp + gmtOffset;

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            long localNow = c.getTimeInMillis();

            // ToDo: show timespan of (localTimestamp - localNow) in human readable format e.g. 2h 5min left
```

**Solution:** That's how I solved it according to your ideas. Thanks!

```
    final CharSequence timespan = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
            localTimestamp,
            localNow,
            DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS,
            DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try as  following code : -

```
    long gmtOffset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
    long utcTimestamp = item.getExpirationDate();

    DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(utcTimestamp, gmtOffset, DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);
```

Comment: I'm using a slightly different function and parameters. But the idea was correct. Therefore I accept your answer and will post my solution above.

Answer (score 2):

you need to do via SimpleDateFormat method. Please check the example.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
String formattedTime = outputFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: but this will have an output of 02:15 and not 2hours 15min. right?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat("hhhh:mmmm a");  please search, how to use SimpleDateFormat to show this type of output. I think, you found it.

Answer (score 1):

The most simplest and easiest way to do this is using this,

```
int seconds = (int) (milliseconds / 1000) % 60 ;
int minutes = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60)) % 60);
int hours   = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
```

This is how you can get "hours", "minutes" or "seconds" from your `localTimestamp - localNow`

Just use,

```
System.out.println(hours + " hours " + minutes + " min");
```

This will display time in exactly the way you want. Hope it helps.

Comment: That's a short handed solution because it does not take care about locale and language. hours and minutes are named differently in English, German, Russian, etc.